# If a group of 9 kids have won a total of 100 trophies, then at least one of the 9 kids has won at least 12 trophies.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic

How would I go about proving this statement using contradiction?
This is what I have so far:

p: A group of 9 kids have won a total of 100 trophies

q: At least one of the 9 kids has won at least 12 trophies.

p → q

Then by contradiction: p → q ≡ p ^ ¬q, such that (¬q: Not one of the 9 kids has won at least 12 trophies)

After this I'm stuck am I suppose to show more proof and how would I write my conclusion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would be a basic application of the pigeonhole principle, but let's take it from a more logical standpoint.

You want to show at least one kid has won twelve trophies by contradiction. So instead suppose the opposite: all kids have not won twelve or more trophies, i.e. all kids have won eleven or fewer trophies.

How can we show this is false? Well, we know we have $9$ kids, and in the worst case scenario each has won $11$ trophies. $100$ have been awarded. What is the contradiction here?

Solution:

> The contradiction is that, if no kid has won $12$ trophies, then all of them have won at most $11$ trophies. That means $9 \cdot 11 = 99$ trophies (or fewer) have been awarded, contradicting that $100$ have been awarded since $99 < 100$.

---

More on the pigeonhole principle can be found elsewhere. It is used a lot in problems like these, and even this has a similar flair to it:

- Wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pigeonhole_principle
- Art of Problem Solving: https://artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php/Pigeonhole_Principle
- Brilliant: https://brilliant.org/wiki/pigeonhole-principle-definition/